# How to set up asset fingerprinting in Play 2.3.4?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Versions:

- play 2.3.4
- sbt 0.13.1
- scala 2.11.2

I've followed the [documentation on playframework.com](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets) to enable fingerprinting on public assets, but calls to `routes.Assets.versioned` never produce a versioned filename with a digest hash.

Relevant lines in build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.2"
pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest)
```

Relevant lines in project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.5")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")
```

Relevant lines in conf/routes:

```
GET    /assets/*file    controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

And the main template:

```
@(title: String, lang: String, cssClasses: String, bodyContents: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="@lang">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascript/components/main.js")"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="layout @cssClasses">
    @bodyContents
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output is always:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="el">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>[title]</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/javascript/components/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I get no compiler errors.  The fingerprinting just "doesn't work".  I assume I am missing something simple, but I cannot see it.

Other notes:

- running `find . -name "*.js"` in the root of the project shows no files that have a digest appended to the beginning, as the documentation suggests
- I've run `sbt clean dist` to generate a production mode release and the behavior is the same

Can anyone advise?

Thank you!

NB: I've started looking through the generated class in `target/src_managed/main/routes_reverseRouting.scala` to debug the generated `versioned` method, but this seems like overkill for something that is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 8):

First off, you should update to sbt 0.13.5, because sbt-web and its plugins use an sbt feature called "auto-plugins" that was introduced in 0.13.5.

**The asset pipeline is by the way not triggered in development mode**, you have to test via `sbt start` (or `sbt dist` but that takes more time).

The `versioned` method just checks if an asset has a companion with the `.md5` suffix. You should check if these files exist in `target/web`.

Comment: I've upgraded to use activator, which wraps 0.13.5 and the result is the same.  I'm seeing .md5 files, but (1) none of the javascript is hashed, and (2) sbt-digest is hashing precompiled .scss files instead of the compiled .css files (we are using sbt-sass plugin -- which I realize may be causing the issue with CSS, but it shouldn't affect javascript).  The only files correctly hashed are pngs.

Comment: Activator uses 0.13.5, but do your project? Check `project/build.properties`. Can you try without the SASS plugin, maybe it's causing the issue?

Comment: It was the sass plugin, it was just patched a few hours ago.  See https://github.com/ShaggyYeti/sbt-sass/pull/13 for details.

Comment: Here is a trend that helped me https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/5ER6ZwCJY94

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can remember I had the same problem a couple of weeks ago. Change the asset route to:

```
GET   /web/assets/*file   controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file:Asset)
```

(See the "`file:Asset`" - it seems that "`Asset`" is required if I remember correctly)

Comment: We're specifying the `Asset` type but the result is the same

Answer (score 4):

If the rjs task of the pipeline encounters some problem, then the digest task may not work properly. For  instance, this happens when the default main entry point for rjs is not found:

```
Error: Error: .../target/web/rjs/appdir/javascripts/main.js does not exist.
```

In this particular case, setting the sbt key `RjsKeys.mainModule` to the right value solves the problem and *.js files are properly fingerprinted.

Comment: We were also getting this error -- thanks for the tip.