# Play Framework not picking latest changes in Javascript and CSS

Tags: playframework

Whenever I make changes to my CSS file, Play framework does not pick the latest file. It seems it has cached an old version and keeps using it. How could I enforce that the file should be picked from server, not from browser cache (or wherever it is picking the css, javascript files from)?

I am running the server on local machine and use localhost:9000 to access the server

Comment: Are you certain its not the browser caching local resources?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development

Answer (score 2):

You need to use versioned assets. Make sure that you use `controllers.Assets.versioned` in `routes`:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

In HTML template:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And do not forget to configure versioning in the `build.sbt`

```
// Production.
pipelineStages := Seq(digest) 

// Development.
pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(digest)
```

You need to have `digist` plugin enabled in `project\plugins.sbt` as well

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.1")
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<script src="/assets/javascripts/a7c0637aa0972b62ef0c436a66be57b1-hello.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So it will not have the cache problem because file name will be new after every update of the file.

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt-digest
- [How to set up asset fingerprinting in Play 2.3.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732350/how-to-set-up-asset-fingerprinting-in-play-2-3-4)
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

Comment: Thanks. I am on Play 2.2.6, sbt 0.13.0. Earlier I was using `<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/Example 1-3.js")"></script>`. I changed it to `<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.Assets.versioned("javascripts/Example 1-3.js")"></script>`. made the change in build.sbt and plugins.sbt as well. But my Javascript didnt load. I think `pipelineStages` isn't defined for the version of play I am using.

Comment: You was correct - my post was not enough clear, so return back your changes. I still think your versioned pipeline does not work correctly.